# Docker exit code 0 issue

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, fastapi

Here is my logs after trying to dockerizing a fastapi script:

```
$ docker-compose logs -f
Attaching to docker-name
docker-name exited with code 0
```

Here is my docker compose file:

```
version: '3'  

services:
  observatory-service:
    build: ./observatory  
    volumes:
      - ./observatory:/usr/src/app 
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

docker file:

```
FROM python:3.9

COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD ["python", "/usr/src/app/api.py"]
```

api.py:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return { "Lux app": "Welcome to Lux app" }

@app.post("/extract_text")
def ali():
    return {"Hello": "World"}
```

I am sure it goes through api.py but it exits out of it without error. I am running this on Windows docker.

Comment: Where's your python imports in api.py such as `from fastapi import FastAPI`?

Comment: @AlexandreJuma  yeah, I have that installed. Otherwise, I would receive an import error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're directly calling the fastAPI server script with python and not wrapped with a ASGI web server such as Uvicorn. This is explained in the [debugging page of fastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/debugging/).

I tested with latest versions of fastapi/uvicorn and it works just fine. I suggest you make these two changes:

1 - Add this line to your `requirements.txt` file:

```
uvicorn
```

2- Then add the first line and the two last lines to the end of your `api.py` file:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return { "Lux app": "Welcome to Lux app" }

@app.post("/extract_text")
def ali():
    return {"Hello": "World"}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Result of `GET /`

```
{"Lux app":"Welcome to Lux app"}
```

Finally, another alternative would be [following the docker guide provided by fastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/docker/) which solves this easily by calling your fastapi module directly with uvicorn. This will achieve the same as above.

Example of `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /code
COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt
COPY ./app /code/app
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked and now I have a running docker. 
Another question, do you know why I receive this error when I try to have the POST command? in next comment:

Comment: [error] 34#34: *4 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/extract_text" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.128.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /extract_text HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000", referrer: "http://localhost:8000/"

Comment: Please open a new question with refactored code/artifacts and logs. We should keep this answer related to the original question scope.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72220695/interaction-between-two-containers-in-a-docker